# Tidyr spread não retorna aos dados originais

Tags: r, tidyverse

Considere o `data.frame`:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  a = replicate(6, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  b = rep(c(LETTERS[1:5]), times = 1, each = 6)
)
```

Uso de `gather`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df_1 %<>% as_tibble

x <- df_1 %>% 
  select_at(vars(num_range('a.', 1:3))) %>% 
  gather(key = 'factors', value = 'case') %>% 
  print()

# A tibble: 90 x 2
   factors  case
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 a.1      91.0
 2 a.1      56.2
 3 a.1      34.0
 4 a.1      85.1
 5 a.1      66.2
 6 a.1      21.7
 7 a.1      29.8
 8 a.1      80.3
 9 a.1      59.8
 10 a.1      85.4
# … with 80 more rows
```

Uso de `spread` para retornar aos dados originais:

```
y <- x %>% 
  spread(key = factors, value = case)
```

> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), (31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60), (61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90)
>   Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Para resolver isso (em parte), usei `mutate` com `row_number()`:

```
 y <- x %>% 
    mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(key = factors, value = case) %>% 
    print()

# A tibble: 90 x 4
       n   a.1   a.2   a.3
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  91.0    NA    NA
 2     2  56.2    NA    NA
 3     3  34.0    NA    NA
 4     4  85.1    NA    NA
 5     5  66.2    NA    NA
 6     6  21.7    NA    NA
 7     7  29.8    NA    NA
 8     8  80.3    NA    NA
 9     9  59.8    NA    NA
10    10  85.4    NA    NA
# … with 80 more rows
```

As três colunas são retornadas, mas os casos não apresentam correspondência (ou seja, ao lado de cada valor, existe um dado faltante - `NA`). Como ajusto isso com alguma função do `tidyverse` de modo a deixar o meu `data.frame` com 30 linhas  e não 90?

Comment: Tem que incluir um `group_by(factor)` antes do `mutate(n = row_number())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É preciso acionar a função `group_by`  antes de `mutate`, como citou o @Tomás nos comentários. A função ficaria assim:

```
library(tidyverse)    

y <- x %>% 
  group_by(factors) %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(key = factors, value = case) %>% 
  print()

# A tibble: 30 x 4
       n   a.1   a.2   a.3
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  85.2  38.8  78.4
 2     2  84.2  82.4  21.2
 3     3  58.1  49.9  77.1
 4     4  57.0  85.9  62.4
 5     5  20.9  93.9  97.8
 6     6  59.3  91.6  59.2
 7     7  33.6  90.8  30.9
 8     8  44.0  50.8  81.4
 9     9  23.7  69.5  33.0
10    10  35.6  62.3  25.1
# ... with 20 more rows
```